# How to verify if WatiN new browser window is closed or not when submit button is clicked

Tags: popup, watin

I have a scenario where I click a link on the main browser window and a new popup window (browser window not alert or confirm) is opened.

After performing some operations, I click Submit button expecting that the new popup/browser window is closed. The effect will be shown in the main window.

Now, I want to verify whether the new popup/window is closed or not? How to do this?

```
var popup = br.AttachTo(Find.ByTitle("New Window");
popup.TextField("name").Value = "Part1*";
popup.Button("Search").Click();
popup.CheckBox("Part1").Checked = true;
popup.Button(Find.ByValue("Submit")).Click();
popup.WaitUntilClosed(30); // this is what I want to implement or
VerifyWindowClosed(popup, 30); // Wait for 30 secs with interval of 500 ms till popup is closed. Throw exception at timeout of 30 sec
```

Thanks for any good suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question and show example we will need 2 html files.
File 1 - 1.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Text link tag - by www.rapidtables.com -->
<a href="2.html"  target="_blank">Print</a>
</body>
</html>
```

File 2 - 2.html

```
<head>
<title>Popup</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function windowClose() { 
window.open('','_parent',''); 
window.close();
} 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="Close this window" onclick="windowClose();">
</body>
```

And here is WatIn solution :

```
 WatiN.Core.Settings.WaitUntilExistsTimeOut = 5;
        IE ieBrowser = new IE(@"c:\Page\1.html");
        var instances = new IECollection(true);
        Debug.WriteLine("Instances : " + instances.Count);
        var printElement = ieBrowser.Element(Find.By("target", "_blank"));
        if (printElement != null)
        {
            printElement.Click();
        }
        instances = new IECollection(true);
        Debug.WriteLine("Instances : " + instances.Count);
        IE poppedUpBrowser = IE.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByUrl(url => url.Contains(@"C:\Page\2.html")));

        if (poppedUpBrowser != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Second window exists..");
        }

        poppedUpBrowser.WaitForComplete();
        Debug.WriteLine("Waiting...");
        var button = poppedUpBrowser.Element(Find.By("type", "button"));

        if (button != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Button not null");

            button.ClickNoWait();
        }
        instances = new IECollection(true);
        Debug.WriteLine("Instances : " + instances.Count);
```

In Debug Window you can see changing number of instances :

```
Instances : 1
Instances : 2
Second window exists..
Waiting...
Button not null
Instances : 1
```

So you can be sure that window was closed because number of instances changed. I hope this will help.

For FireFox case :

```
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses("."))
        {
            try
            {
                if (p.MainWindowTitle.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (p.MainWindowTitle.Contains("fox"))
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("-------------------------");
                        Debug.WriteLine("\r\n Window Title:" + p.MainWindowTitle.ToString());
                        Debug.WriteLine("-------------------------");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
}
```

And you will see in Debug ( then you can count, compare, make a list etc. )

```
-------------------------

Window Title:Mozilla Firefox
-------------------------

Window Title:Popup - Mozilla Firefox
```

Comment: I will try the above one but I wanted a generic stuff which can be used for both `IE` and `Firefox`. `IECollection` is `IE` specific and cannot be applied for `Browser` in general. Have you implemented something like `BrowserCollection`??

Comment: Nope. As far as I know there is not something like that for FF. You can use instead. GetProcess(".")